# Collapsing/grouping several lines of code

Tags: python-3.x, notepad++

I am using this piece of code for about 30 different facilities:

```
#Facility 1 emails
path = 'C:\\path\\tofolder'
newpath1 = str(path)+str(theyear)
if not os.path.exists(newpath1):
        os.makedirs(newpath1)

newpath = str(newpath1)+'\\'+str(name)+' '+str(theyear)
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.makedirs(newpath)

pat = str(newpath)+'\\*'
if any(os.path.isfile(file) for file in glob.glob(pat)) or today.day < 20:
    print("Tank inspection not due")
else:
    fromaddr = 'email@gmail.com'
    toaddrs  = 'email2@gmail.com'
    SUBJECT = "Tank inspections"
    TEXT = 'Our records indicate that you have not yet completed the inspection'
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, TEXT)
    username = 'email@gmail.com'
    password = 'pass'
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, message)
    server.quit()
```

The code works fine, however, I have about 900 lines of code that I need to traverse.  Is there any way to group this piece of code so I can collapse it to be able to navigate better?  I'm using notepad++ and very new to python, so I'm not sure if this technique is available.  Right now the only code I can collapse are the if statements.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really adamant about being able to collapse it you can put all those statements into a function and just call the function.  You should be able to collapse the whole function in notepad++

```
def function_name():
    <all those statements>

function_name()
```

Oh wow, just realized that you have probably copied and pasted this code 30 times in your script, read up on how functions work to collapse the 900 lines into something more like 50

Comment: And modules as well.